# Looping on variables with a condition in bash (Starting services in a specific order)

Tags: linux, bash

I'm creating a script in bash to perform the below use cases,

- Finding specific services based on specific words on their names
- Starting these services **in a specific order like: service_3, service_2 and so on**
- **Before starting the next service, It will make sure that the previous one is fully started and if not, It will wait (For example: 4 minutes) until it's fully started and if it's still not fully started, It will try to stop then start it, It will print out a message that the service needs an investigation and break the flow**

This is my progress, Firstly, I've found the services based on some words that only exists with their names as below,

```
service_1=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text1 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')
service_2=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text2 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')
service_3=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text3 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')
```

Then, I've stopped them in the order i want with checking if the third service is stopped before proceeding with the second one as below,

```
if [ ! -z "$service_3" ] //if service exists
then
      systemctl start $service_3
else
      :
fi

service_3_status=$(systemctl status $service_3 | grep -e "active")
if [ $service_3_status == "active"]
      if [ ! -z "$service_2" ] //if service exists
      then
            systemctl start $service_2
      else
            :
      fi
else
systemctl start $service_3
fi

service_2_status=$(systemctl status $service_2 | grep -e "active")
if [ $service_2_status == "active"]
      if [ ! -z "$service_1" ] //if service exists
      then
            systemctl start $service_1
      else
            :
      fi
else
systemctl start $service_2
fi
```

What i want to do is to loop on the services to make sure that the third service is fully started before moving to the second one and so on and if there is a service that is not fully started, It will wait till it's fully started (For example: 4 minutes) but not moving to the next service and if it's still stopped, It will try to stop and start it and if it is still not started it will print out a message with the service name that it cannot be started and this needs an investigation, As per the above code, It will try to start the service if it is not fully started and at the same time it will proceed with the next one which is not the behavior i want, What is the proper way to do this ?

Comment: `if systemctl is-active foo.service >/dev/null; then foo; else bar; fi`

Comment: Thanks @Jetchisel for your input but you only replace the way of checking if the service is active or not but the problem still exists, What if the service is inactive ?, I want to make it wait till the previous service is fully started then retry to start the service again (If service_3 is still inactive, Wait till it becomes active then try to start service_2 again), That's the behavior i want to do, I think this should be made using a loop with a condition to handle the second part of the main condition (Checking if the service is active or not).

Comment: As an aside, that's a [useless `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) spiced up with a [useless `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: Thanks @tripleee for your input, I've found the below approach to detect if service is active and it works, `if [ $(systemctl is-active $service_1) == "active" ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a quick check on systemd's docs, there are options/process to wait/check for the service or if there are unit files, but here is a nested loop that might do what you wanted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: Do your variable service assignment here

for service in "$service_3" "$service_2" "$service_1"; do
  if [[ -n "$service" ]]; then
    systemctl start "$service"
    until systemctl status active "$service" >/dev/null; do
      sleep 10
      systemctl start "$service"
    done
  fi
done
```

---

- Add a `sleep` after starting the service if needed.

---

See
[how-can-a-systemd-service-flag-that-it-is-ready-so-that-other-services-can-wait](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331693/how-can-a-systemd-service-flag-that-it-is-ready-so-that-other-services-can-wait) for more info on howto do it the `systemd` way.

- [delay-systemd-service-if-file-exist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388483/delay-systemd-service-if-file-exist)
- [the-proper-way-to-test-if-a-service-is-running-in-a-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396630/the-proper-way-to-test-if-a-service-is-running-in-a-script)
- [systemctl-check-if-a-unit-service-or-target-exists](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/539147/systemctl-check-if-a-unit-service-or-target-exists)

---

It looks like `init.d` all over again though...

Comment: Uh, probably instead explain the dependency mechanism of `systemd`

Comment: I don't know systemd/systectl that well, I just did some unit files and services. I just added a link for the OP to check.

Comment: @Jetchisel Thanks for your input, I've tried your provided solution and it really helps, We can use also my suggested approach, I've tested it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
    
service_1=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text1 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')
service_2=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text2 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')
service_3=$(ls /etc/systemd/system | grep -e text3 | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')
    
if [ ! -z "$service_3" ] # if service exists
then
      systemctl stop $service_3
      sleep 30 # 30s
      echo "$service_3 stopped"
fi

if [ ! -z "$service_3" ] # if service exists
then
      if [ $(systemctl is-active $service_3) == "inactive" ] # if service is not active
      then
            if [ ! -z "$service_2" ] # if service exists
            then
                  systemctl stop $service_2
                  sleep 30 # 30s
                  echo "$service_2 stopped"
            fi
      else
          echo "$service_3 is either active or failed, Please check !"
          exit
      fi
elif [ ! -z "$service_2" ]
then
      systemctl stop $service_2
      sleep 30 # 30s
      echo "$service_2 stopped"
fi

if [ ! -z "$service_2" ] # if service exists
then
      if [ $(systemctl is-active $service_2) == "inactive" ] # if service is not active
      then
            if [ ! -z "$service_1" ] # if service exists
            then
                  systemctl stop $service_1
                  sleep 30 # 30s
                  echo "$service_1 stopped"
            fi
      else
          echo "$service_2 is either active or failed, Please check !"
          exit
      fi
elif [ ! -z "$service_1" ]
then
      systemctl stop $service_1
      sleep 30 # 30s
      echo "$service_1 stopped"
fi
```

Comment: This still suffers from the problems I pointed out earlier. I'm not sure why you need Awk at all there; I'm guessing you would want something like `service1=/etc/systemd/system/*text1*` possibly with some follow-up to check that the result contains exactly one existing file.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I think both approaches can work.

Comment: The crucial question is under which circumstances they will break. [Don't parse `ls` output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) because it's brittle and error-prone.